# bcrypt is causing POST request 500?

Tags: node.js, next.js, bcrypt, vercel

I have no idea why but I’ve started getting these errors on Vercel, but no issues on LocalHost, even doing `yarn build && yarn start`

[image]

I have made sure that I'm using CORS in Next.js

[image]

And my api code

```js
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { connectPrisma } from 'utils/connectPrisma'

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const { email, password } = req.body

    if (!email || !password) return res.status(422).json({ error: 'Please complete all fields' })

    try {
      const { client } = await connectPrisma()
      const user = await client.user.findFirst({ where: { email } })

      if (user) {
        return res.status(422).json({ error: `User already exists with that email` })
      }

      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 8)
      await client.user.create({ data: { email: email, password: hashedPassword } })

      res.status(201).json({ message: 'Success test' })
    } catch {
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Unable to insert user' })
    }
    return
  }

  return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Invalid request' })
}
```

As soon as i comment the

```
      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 8)
```

I'm able to do POST request

Comment: Yep i can confirm using older version v4 of bcrypt i don't have this issue.

Comment: What's the error message?